Dynamically filter select options in an objectbrick
I have a Pimcore class with a Type field (selection) and a Products field (objectbricks). In the admin panel, I need the options available in the Products dropdown to dynamically change based on the value of the Type field. For example, if a user selects “Car”, the Products dropdown should only list object bricks associated with “Car”.
How can I implement this in Pimcore admin panel?

You can add a databinding to the selectfield (dropdown field) and to the store's filter. It might be necessary to add a formula.
Ext.define('VM1', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.VM1',

    data: {
        FirstNameFilter: ''
    },

    stores: {
        users: {
            model: 'Fiddle.User',
            storeId: 'user',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'users',
            },
            filters: [{
                property: 'FirstName',
                operator: 'like',
                value: '{FirstNameFilter}',
             disableOnEmpty:true
            }]
        }
    }
});

The full example can be found here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3sp8
